# Returning a slice from a DataFrame along with an int in a tuple

Tags: python

I'm passing a dataframe to a function and slicing it up along with making a comparison and attempting to return a tuple with the slice and the classification (int) of the comparison like so:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    for pos in range(0, len(seq) - (size+1), 1):
        if seq.iloc[pos + (size-1), 3] < seq.iloc[pos + size, 3]:
            dir = 1
            theTuple = (seq[pos:pos + size], dir)
            return theTuple
        else:
            dir = -1
            theTuple = (seq[pos:pos + size], dir)
            return theTuple
```

I'm then iterating over the collection to organize some results like so:

```
    cnt = 10000
    for i in chunker(df, 15):
        cnt += 1
        filename = 'DATA_SLICE_'
        filename += str(cnt)
        segment = i[0]
        bias = i[1]
        if bias == 1:
            side = 'Positive/'
        else:
            side = 'Negative/'
        mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='g',down='r')
        s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=mc, gridstyle='')
        fig = mpf.plot(segment, type='renko', renko_params=dict(brick_size=0.0015),
            style=s,
            title = '',
            ylabel = '',
            axisoff=True,
            mav = (3, 5, 7),
            figsize = (3.0, 3.0),
            savefig='../imgs/' + side + filename)
```

It seems my slice of dataframe comes thru in the iterator i; however, there is no access to the second element of the tuple returned from the chunker function.  The slice is in scope and useable.  Am I losing scope on the tuple as I attempt to iterate?  I'm new to python.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your code does what you think it does. Your function `chunker` exits on the first iteration of the `for` loop for `pos=0` and returns a single tuple `(seq[0:size], dir)` where `dir` is either 1 or -1 depending on your condition. Then your loop in the main body  `for i in chunker(df, 15):` iterates over the values of this tuple so on first pass `i` is set to the slice of `seq` and on the second to `dir`. I am actually surprised it is not erroring down the line. Possibly you wanted to do something like this

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    tuples = []
    for pos in range(0, len(seq) - (size+1), 1):
        if seq.iloc[pos + (size-1), 3] < seq.iloc[pos + size, 3]:
            dir = 1
            theTuple = (seq[pos:pos + size], dir)
        else:
            dir = -1
            theTuple = (seq[pos:pos + size], dir)
        tuples.append(theTuple)
    return tuples
```

also perhaps you meant

```
    for pos in range(0, len(seq) - (size+1), size):
```

for your `range` (note I replaced `1` with `size` for the third argument)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I see now what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but your if statement doesn't seem to be indented properly. Might be why you're not getting what you expect. Maybe.

```
    if bias == 1:
         side = 'Positive/'
    else:
         side = 'Negative/'
```

Comment: My indent was correct in the editor.  Copy / Paste Error... Sorry